# ASP.NET MVC Forget Password email link not formatting as Html

Tags: c#, html, email, smtp, mailmessage

I am trying to set up a forgot password feature, but I can't get the body of the email formatted with links. I think the email is not set up for Html.

```
 void sendMail(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        #region formatter
        string text = string.Format("", message.Subject, message.Body);
        string html = "";

        html += HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(@"" + message.Body);
        #endregion

        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email"].ToString());
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(message.Destination));
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        msg.Subject = message.Subject;
        msg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(html, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html));
        msg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(html, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html));

        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp-mail.outlook.com", Convert.ToInt32(587));
        System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"].ToString());
        smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

        smtpClient.Send(msg);
    }
```

How I use it:

```
await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Holiday Tracker Reset Password", "Please reset your password by using the following link.   <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here </a> ");
```

I would like the code to work so the email has a clickable link instead of just the long string of the url.

Comment: How does UserManager know to call sendMail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided any sample of your message body data, or sample source markup of the generated emails, so it's hard to be 100% of the root cause, but here are a few little issues here which might be contributing:

1) You never actually set the main body text of your email. You set alternative views, but not the base body. So even though you set the IsBodyHtml option, there's nothing for it to act upon.

2) You've added two identical alternative views. It probably doesn't matter, but it's clearly redundant. If you've set the body to HTML, and then actually included body text, you shouldn't need these alternative views anyway.

3) The above are niggles, but I think this is the clincher: I strongly suspect you have misunderstood what [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmlencode?view=netframework-4.8) does.

Consider the following example:

```
string myString = "<b>Hello World</b>";
// Encode the string.
string myEncodedString = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(myString);

Console.WriteLine($"HTML Encoded string is: {myEncodedString}");
StringWriter myWriter = new StringWriter();

// Decode the encoded string.
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(myEncodedString, myWriter);
string myDecodedString = myWriter.ToString();
Console.Write($"Decoded string of the above encoded string is: {myDecodedString}");
```

This will output:

```
HTML Encoded string is: &lt;b&gt;Hello World&lt;/b&gt;
Decoded string of the above encoded string is: <b>Hello World</b>
```

Live Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9j46WN

As you can see, encoding a string containing HTML will convert the HTML control characters into their encoded representation. This is generally used to ensure the characters are **not** treated as HTML when viewed (i.e. they are seen as pieces of text to be displayed on screen, not interpreted as part of the HTML document's markup). This is the exact opposite of what you want.

e.g. when I put those two strings into *this* HTML page as raw markup (rather than in a "code" block), it comes out as:

---

HTML Encoded string is: <b>Hello World</b>

Decoded string of the above encoded string is: **Hello World**

---

Notice how the encoded one *displays* the HTML rather than *using* it?

So I think you can drop the Html-encoding. Assuming you are already supplying HTML markup to your method in `message.Body`, then you can use it as-is. And if you set your message body in the normal way, you should be able to dispense with the alternative views as well. Here's what I think your code should be changed to:

```
void sendMail(IdentityMessage message)
{
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    msg.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email"].ToString());
    msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(message.Destination));
    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
    msg.Body = message.Body;
    msg.Subject = message.Subject;

    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp-mail.outlook.com", Convert.ToInt32(587));
    System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"].ToString());
    smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

    smtpClient.Send(msg);
}
```